# How to access a configuration file in a different folder for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following configuration js file

```
const firebase = require('firebase')

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "blahblahblah",
    authDomain: "ivrs-fjj.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://ivrs-fjj.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "ivrs-fjj",
    storageBucket: "ivrs-fjj.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "10387869293211",
    appId: "1:1038786929211:web:6ed1a5djf9855105ef21e",
    measurementId: "G-ZTY9VS9GV9"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.database();
module.exports = {db}
```

Then in my app.js I have the following:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const {db} = require('./config/firebaseConfiguration.js');

....

app.get('', (req, res) => {

    // Display the db
    console.log(db)

    res.render('index') 

})
app.listen(port, () => console.info(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

Lastly, my package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Market",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Marketplace",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

and the folder structure I am using is as follows:

```
Market
---config
-------firebaseConfig.js
---node_modules
---views
---public
---app.js
---package.json
```

I get following error when I start the express server:

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:438
throw e;
^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /Users/Documents/Market/node_modules/firebase/package.json
at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object. (/Users/Documents/Market/config/firebaseConfiguration.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are exporting as ECMAScript module and importing as CommonJS?

Comment: @GuerricP sorry I am new to node can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well `import` and `export` keywords are ECMAScript module keywords while `module.exports` and `require` are CommonJS keywords. While they can interoperate, using them both in a codebase that you own is kinda strange.

Comment: @GuerricP i have edited my questions and added the `"type": "module"`, which is in the package.json file

Comment: I have also edited the error message being thrown

Comment: I see that you also changed `require` to `import` does it work now?

Comment: No it does not, i updated the entire question with the error message i get now

Comment: I think that firebase is not designed to be used in an ECMAScript module. Try reverting your modifications and using `require` instead of `import`

Comment: @GuerricP if i do that, then i get the following error at the lines of code `const db = firebase.database();
export {db}` in the firebaseCongifuration.js file. export is unexpected token

Comment: I forgot: also change your `export {db}` with `module.exports = { db }`

Comment: @GuerricP still throws `Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /Users/Documents/Market/node_modules/firebase/package.json` error

Comment: @GuerricP i modified all the code in the question to use `require`

Comment: So I figured out why the error is being thrown. need to have the following `const firebase = require('firebase/app');` Now my question is , it keeps displaying `undefined` in the console log where i have the code `console.log("db connection:", db)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `export default db` instead of `export {db}` or if you want to use the latter you can import it like this

```
const {db} = require('./config/firebaseConfiguration.js');
```

Comment: I get the following error `/Users/Documents/market/config/firebaseConfiguration.js:24
  export default db
  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`